# How to prevent overlapping of shapes in Java FX?

Tags: java, javafx, collision-detection, game-physics

How can I prevent overlapping of shapes in Java FX ?

I already got the collision detection but I don't know what to do next..

```
//THIS IS MY COLLISION DETECTION
public void checkCollision(Characters a, Characters b, Characters c, Characters d)
{
    if(a.getBoundsInParent().intersects(b.getBoundsInParent()))
    {
        info.setText("COLLISION DETECTED TO ENEMY 1");
    }else if(a.getBoundsInParent().intersects(c.getBoundsInParent())){
        info.setText("COLLISION DETECTED TO ENEMY 2");
    }else if(a.getBoundsInParent().intersects(d.getBoundsInParent())){
        info.setText("COLLISION DETECTED TO ENEMY 3");
    }else{
        info.setText("");
    }
}


  //AND THIS IS MY EVENT ON KEY PRESSED
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP){
            player.setTranslateY(player.getTranslateY() - 10);
        }else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN){
            player.setTranslateY(player.getTranslateY() + 10);
        }else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT){
            player.setTranslateX(player.getTranslateX() - 10);
        }else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT){
            player.setTranslateX(player.getTranslateX() + 10);
        }

        checkCollision(player, enemy, enemy2, enemy3);

    });
```

Comment: What exactly you want to happen? One object push the other back, or it must block?

Comment: It must block like a wall. A solid box. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it collides and you wish it to stop, simply don't modify the translate values.

That's all one could get from the pieces you provide.